# ruby regex: How to extract string from url

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

not very familiar with rubular, would like to know how to use Ruby regex to extract "postreview-should-be-the-cause" from

```
"{\"source_url\"=>\"http://testing.com/projects/postreview-should-be-the-cause\"}"
```

the best I am getting is

```
check_user = url.split(/\b(\w+)\b/)
=> ["{\"", "source_url", "\"=>\"", "http", "://", "localhost", ":", "3000", "/", "projects", "/", "postreview", "-", "should", "-", "be", "-", "the", "-", "cause", "\"}"]
```

Still trying various ways. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract that substring from the given string, you could use the following to match instead of split.

```
result = url.match(/\w+(?:-\w+)+/)
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/241573)

Comment: I am new to match, just wondering if this is the right way use match? 

Model.find_by(puts result)

Comment: I think I got it, but do let me know if "Model.find_by(puts result)" is valid. =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string.scan` instead of `string.split`

```
> "{\"source_url\"=>\"http://testing.com/projects/postreview-should-be-the-cause\"}".scan(/(?<=\/)[^\/"]*(?=[^\/]*$)/)[0]
=> "postreview-should-be-the-cause"
```

Comment: Thanks avinash! wow, didnt know about scan. So far, string.scan gave me this output. check_user = url.scan(/\b(\w+)\b/)
=> [["source_url"], ["http"], ["localhost"], ["3000"], ["projects"], ["postreview"], ["should"], ["be"], ["the"], ["cause"]], how can I merge them back to "postreview-should-be-the-cause"? cause I need to match this later with another model.

Comment: print the index 0 and get the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
\/(?!.*\/)
```

Split by this.And get the second component.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/48